# Take use input in sets and Dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dfa

```
   class DFA:
current_state = None;
def __init__(self, states, alphabet, transition_function, start_state, accept_states):
    self.states = states;
    self.alphabet = alphabet;
    self.transition_function = transition_function;
    self.start_state = start_state;
    self.accept_states = accept_states;
    self.current_state = start_state;
    return;

def transition_to_state_with_input(self, input_value):
    if ((self.current_state, input_value) not in self.transition_function.keys()):
        self.current_state = None;
        return;
    self.current_state = self.transition_function[(self.current_state, input_value)];
    return;

def in_accept_state(self):
    return self.current_state in accept_states;

def go_to_initial_state(self):
    self.current_state = self.start_state;
    return;

def run_with_input_list(self, input_list):
    self.go_to_initial_state();
    for inp in input_list:
        self.transition_to_state_with_input(inp);
        continue;
    return self.in_accept_state();
pass;



  states = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

 tf = dict();
          tf[(0, 'a')] = 1;
          tf[(0, 'b')] = 2;
          tf[(0, 'c')] = 3;
          tf[(0, 'd')] = 0;
          tf[(1, 'a')] = 1;
          tf[(1, 'b')] = 2;
         tf[(1, 'c')] = 3;
         tf[(1, 'd')] = 0;
          tf[(2, 'a')] = 1;
          tf[(2, 'b')] = 2;
         tf[(2, 'c')] = 3;
    tf[(2, 'd')] = 0;
    tf[(3, 'a')] = 1;
    tf[(3, 'b')] = 2;
    tf[(3, 'c')] = 3;
    tf[(3, 'd')] = 0;
    start_state = 0;
    accept_states = {2, 3};

    d = DFA(states, alphabet, tf, start_state, accept_states);

    inp_program = list('abcdabcdabcd');

    print (d.run_with_input_list(inp_program))
```

This is DFA (deterministic automata) program which takes States and Alphabets (as hard coded values) and then add them in dictionary 
and for each states and alphabets we give some value to dictionary

I want to make this program user defined by
1. Takes input from user and add in set named "Set"
2. Takes input from user and add in set named "alphabets"
3 for each pair of sets and alphabets ask user to add value

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You do not return anything with your methods.

Comment: run_with_input_list only this methods only returns